# Pagination in Codeigniter without page reload

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Is there any way in codeigniter Pagination, such that when I click on next page in links my page should not get reload? 
I am done with pagination But I am not able to solve this query. 
Please Help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: What you're asking is creating an AJAX pagination: The "not reloading page" effect is achieved when you use AJAX, that is, programming into the client side to call the server and only reload a part of the website.

That's said, if you wanted to get that, you should look for something like: [Codeigniter jquery ajax pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402714/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-pagination)